# RemoveProfile Command not working in mdm

Tags: iphone, mdm, profiles

RemoveProfile command is not working properly for me.

I am setting the proper profile identifier with below xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC '-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN' 'http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd'><plist version='1.0'>
                        <dict>
                        <key>Command</key>
                                <dict>
                                    <key>RequestType</key>
                                    <string>RemoveProfile</string>
                                    <key>Identifier</key>
                                    <string>com.apple.mgmt.mdmA3727E23-7914-59A6-FDCE-D79D9B42A209</string>
                                </dict>
                        <key>CommandUUID</key>
                        <string>B733FE25-101E-4959-4FAD-7262D7774169</string>
                        </dict>

                    </plist>
```

Also when I query for profiles installed on device I get this profile installed with same profile identifier.

Can someone guide me whats wrong with the command.

On IPCU, I get the following error:

```
The profile “com.apple.mgmt.mdmA3727E23-7914-59A6-FDCE-D79D9B42A209” is not managed by MDM.
```

If I performed an enterprise wipe i.e. remove the main enrollment profile via the same above command, it removes the enrollment as well as all the associated profiles, so why doesn't it allow me to remove individuals?

Comment: Also the 'Add/Remove Configuration" in the enrollment profile is set to true..

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Two pieces of information:

1) If profile is truely not managed (wasn't installed through MDM), you can't remove it using MDM.

2) I noticed and reported to Apple a bug in which my iOS device lost association between MDM profile and profiles which were installed through MDM. So, you may have seen this bug.